# Jinja2 Whitespace control on {% with %} tag not working as expected

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am running into the issue that a `{% with %}` tag is adding an extra line to my jinja template although I set `trim_blocks=True` and `lstrip_blocks=True` in my `Environment(loader=loader, trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)` class.

Here is the code:

ddl.jinja

```
{{ ddl.input }}
(
{% with columns = ddl.columns %} 
{% include 'columns.jinja' %}
{% endwith %}
);
```

columns.jinja

```
{% for column in columns %}
    {{ column + ',' if not loop.last else column}}
{% endfor %}
```

Output with the extra whitespace line occurring after the open parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE USER
(

    username char(40) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(80) NULL
);
```

Here is the data I am passing to the template:

```py
generator.render_template(template=template, data={"ddl": {"input": "CREATE TABLE USER", "columns": ["username char(40) NOT NULL", "email varchar(80) NULL"]}}
```

I am not sure why the extra whitespace line is being added and although I can remove it using the `-` at the end of my with block, I'd prefer not to as I am not doing that anywhere else in the codebase.

Comment: You have tail **whitespace** at the end of the line with `{% with %}` statement. Just remove it, and rendering should produce expected results.

Answer (score 0):

in `ddl.jinja` you are writting

```
{{ ddl.input }}\n
(\n
{% with columns = ddl.columns %} \n
{% include 'columns.jinja' %}\n
{% endwith %}\n
);
```

So when `generator.render_template` is called with :

- trim_blocks=True -> It impacts `\n` only after blocks (cf https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#high-level-api). So it removes the `\n` in `{% include 'columns.jinja' %}\n` and in `{% endwith %}\n`
- lstrip_blocks=True -> only impacts whitespaces and tabs (not relevant to the question)

You might want to correct `ddl.jinja` into

```
{{ ddl.input }}
(
{% with columns = ddl.columns %}{% include 'columns.jinja' %}{% endwith %}
);
```

Comment: Why is it doing it for the {% with columns = ddl.columns %} but not the {% endwith %}?